# Hard inequality :$\Big(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{1}{c^2+a^2}\Big)^2\geq \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponentiation

I have a hard problem this is it :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a^ab^bc^c=1$ then we have :
>   $$\Big(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{1}{c^2+a^2}\Big)^2\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

I try to use Jensen's ienquality applied to the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ but it doesn't works for all the values .

if we apply Am-Gm it's like Jensen's inequality so I forget this ways .

Maybe If we apply Karamata's inequality but I didn't found the right majorization .

I try also to use Muirhead inequality but without success .

So I'm a bit lost with that if you have a hint or a full answer I will be happy to read your work .

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212184/inequality-fracxx2x2y2-fracyy2y2z2-fraczz2z2x?rq=1

Comment: My usual questions: Where does the inequality come from? Why do you think that it is true? Would this have any applications or is it just a random inequality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nelson Faustino guessed that $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\le 8$. Let us prove it.

*Proof*: We will use the following lemma whose proof is given later.

*Lemma 1*: Let $a, b, c\ge 0$ with $11(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 4(a+b+c) - 45 \le 0$. Then
$(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\le 8$.

Let us begin. Using AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^2} + \frac{1}{(b^2+c^2)^2} + \frac{1}{(c^2+a^2)^2}
\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^2(b^2+c^2)^2(c^2+a^2)^2}}.$$
It suffices to prove that $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\le 8$.
To this end, we have
\begin{align}
&a, b, c > 0, \quad a^ab^bc^c=1 \qquad\qquad (1)\\
\Longrightarrow \quad & a\ln a + b\ln b + c\ln c = 0, \quad 0 < a, b, c < \frac{159}{100}\qquad\qquad (2)\\
\Longrightarrow \quad &11(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 4(a+b+c) - 45 \le 0, \quad a, b, c > 0.
\qquad\qquad (3)
\end{align}
Here, in (2), since $-u\ln u \le \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$ for $u>0$, we have
$a\ln a, b\ln b, c\ln c \le \frac{2}{\mathrm{e}}$ which, when combined with $\frac{159}{100}\ln \frac{159}{100} > \frac{2}{\mathrm{e}}$,
results in $a, b, c < \frac{159}{100}$ (noting that $x \mapsto x\ln x$ is strictly increasing for $x > 1$);
In (3), we have used the fact that
$$x\ln(x) \ge \frac{11}{26}x^2 + \frac{2}{13}x - \frac{15}{26}, \quad \forall 0 < x < \frac{159}{100}.\qquad (4)$$
Then, according to Lemma 1, the desired result follows. We are done.

*Proof of (4)*: It suffices to prove that
$$\ln x \ge \frac{\frac{11}{26}x^2 + \frac{2}{13}x - \frac{15}{26}}{x}, \quad \forall 0 < x < \frac{159}{100}.$$
Let $h(x) = \ln x - \frac{\frac{11}{26}x^2 + \frac{2}{13}x - \frac{15}{26}}{x}$.
We have $h'(x) = -\frac{11(x-1)(x-\frac{15}{11})}{26x^2}$.
Thus, $h(x)$ is decreasing on $(0, 1)$, increasing on $(1, \frac{15}{11})$ and decreasing on $(\frac{15}{11}, \infty)$.
Note that $h(1) = 0$ and $h(\frac{159}{100}) > 0 $. The desired result follows.

*Proof of Lemma 1*: One of the methods is the *uvw* method as follows. However, **I hope to see nice proofs of Lemma 1**.

Let $a+b+c = 3u$, $ab+bc+ca = 3v^2$ and $abc = w^3$.

The constraint $11(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 4(a+b+c) - 45 \le 0$ becomes $11(9u^2 - 6v^2) + 12u - 45 \le 0$. 
The constraint does not involve $w^3$.

We need to prove that $f(w^3) = 8 - (a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2) = w^6+6u(9u^2-6v^2)w^3-81u^2v^4+54v^6+8 \ge 0$.
Since $9u^2 - 6v^2 \ge 0$ and $w^3\ge 0$, $f(w^3)$ is increasing with $w^3$.
Thus, we only need to prove the case when $a=b$ or $c=0$. The rest is not hard and thus omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Define: $$F(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{c^2+a^2}\right)^2$$

By the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), the minimizer of $F$ under the constraint $a^ab^bc^c=1$ must be a critical point of the Lagrangian

$$L(a,b,c,\lambda)=\left(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{c^2+a^2}\right)^2+\lambda(a^ab^bc^c-1)$$

To find the critical points we solve $\nabla L=0$:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda}=a^ab^bc^c-1=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=-\frac{4a}{(a^2+b^2)^3}-\frac{4a}{(a^2+c^2)^3}+\lambda(a^ab^bc^c)(1+\log a)=0$$

and similarly find the equation for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=0$. We got a system of 4 (non-linear) equations with 4 variables.

Let $a,b,c,\lambda$ be a solution. Since $a^ab^bc^c=1$, at least one of $a,b,c$ is $\leq 1$ and at least one is $\geq 1$, so WLOG we can treat two cases: $a\leq b\leq 1\leq c$ and $a\leq 1\leq b\leq c$ .

- First case $a\leq b\leq 1\leq c$: Isolating $\lambda$ in the equations $\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=0$ leads to
  $$\lambda=\left[\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(a^2+c^2)^3}\right]\cdot\frac{a}{1+\log a}=\left[\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(b^2+c^2)^3}\right]\cdot\frac{b}{1+\log b}$$
  If $a<b$ then 
  $$\left[\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(a^2+c^2)^3}\right]>\left[\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(b^2+c^2)^3}\right]$$
  and 
  $$\frac{a}{1+\log a}>\frac{b}{1+\log b}$$
  by contradiction to the equality above. Therefore we conclude $a=b$, and we may reduce our problem to 2 dimensions: Minimize
  $$F(a,a,c)=\frac{1}{4a^4}+2\left(\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}\right)^2$$
  Among all $a,c$ s.t. $a^{2a}c^c=1$. Using the [square super root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Square_super-root) function we put $c=\text{ssrt}(a^{-2a})$ in the above expression and get
  $$G(a)=\frac{1}{4a^4}+2\left(\frac{1}{a^2+\text{ssrt}(a^{-2a})^2}\right)^2$$
  Convince yourself that $G$ attains its minimum at $a=1$ (I used a computer, maybe possible to do it analytically), so to minimize $G$ we must take $a=1$. We conclude $a=b=1$, and then $c=\text{ssrt}(1)=1$ as well.
- Second case $a\leq 1\leq b\leq c$: Isolating $\lambda$ in the equations $\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=0$ leads to
  $$\lambda=\left[\frac{1}{(b^2+a^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(b^2+c^2)^3}\right]\cdot\frac{b}{1+\log b}=\left[\frac{1}{(c^2+a^2)^3}+\frac{1}{(c^2+b^2)^3}\right]\cdot\frac{c}{1+\log c}$$
  If $b<c$ then 
  $$\frac{1}{(b^2+a^2)^3}\frac{b}{1+\log b}>\frac{1}{(c^2+a^2)^3}\frac{c}{1+\log c}$$
  and 
  $$\frac{1}{(b^2+c^2)^3}\frac{b}{1+\log b}>\frac{1}{(c^2+b^2)^3}\frac{c}{1+\log c}$$
  by contradiction to the equality above. Therefore we conclude $b=c$, and continue as in the first case to show $a=b=c=1$.

To conclude: 
$$\min\{F(a,b,c);a^ab^bc^c=1\}=F(1,1,1)=\frac{3}{4}$$

Remark: I may have over-complicated things. If you can show in a more simple way that $a=b=c=\lambda=1$ is the **only** solution to $\nabla L=0$ then you are done.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+\log(x)}$ is increasing when $x\geq 1$ and we are not guaranteed to have $a\leq b\leq 1.$ It could happen that $a<1<b\leq c. $

Comment: @dezdichado You are right. I added this second case.

Answer (score 2):

First, I will ignore the constraint $a^ab^bc^c=1$ to sketch a possible solution for the aforementioned inequality, under an alternative constraint:

Set $x=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}$ and $x=\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}$ and $z=\frac{1}{c^2+a^2}$.

From the aritmetic-geometric inequality
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 3(x^2y^2z^2)^{\frac{1}{3}},
$$
it remains to show that $$(x^2y^2z^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}\geq \frac{1}{4},$$

By noting that
$$ (a^2+b^2)^2(b^2+c^2)^2(c^2+a^2)^2=\frac{1}{x^2y^2z^2},$$ the previous inequality to be shown becomes
$$
(a^2+b^2)^2(b^2+c^2)^2(c^2+a^2)^2 \leq 64.
$$
or equivalently
$$ (a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\leq 8,$$
if we take the square on both sides of the inequality.

Noteworty, if $(a,b),(b,c)$ and $(a,c)$ belong to the closure of the disc $\mathbb{T}$ of radius $\sqrt{2}$:
$$ \overline{\mathbb{T}}=\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2~:~\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\leq \sqrt{2}\},$$
the previous inequality is always satisfied.

Comment: $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\leq 8$ is not true under $a^ab^bc^c = 1$ and what happens if $t$ is not the max of $a,b,c ?$

Comment: A check by desmos seem to suggest that max{a,b,c} can be as large as $e^{W(2/e)}\approx1.589$ which is greater than 1.

Comment: @dezdichado How sure are you that $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\leq 8$ is not true? Seems pretty true to me...

Comment: @EdwardH. Because you can take $a$ as large as you want.

Comment: @dezdichado Not really though, when $a$ is sufficiently large you would just stop getting solutions to $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @EdwardH. yeah you are right.

Comment: Dear all, I redraw my argument on my post. Instead one can replace it by the argument
$$
\left(\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)^2\geq\frac{3}{4t^2},
$$
where $t=\max\{a,b,c\}$.

Thus, the desired inequality holds only it $t\leq1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Making $b = \lambda a, c = \mu a$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{(1+\lambda^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\lambda^2+\mu^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\mu^2+1)^2}\ge \frac 34 a^4
$$

and

$$
a = \frac{1}{(\mu^{\mu}\lambda^{\lambda})^{\frac{1}{1+\lambda+\mu}}}
$$

then if

$$
f(\lambda,\mu) = \frac{1}{(1+\lambda^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\lambda^2+\mu^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\mu^2+1)^2}- \frac 34 \frac{1}{(\mu^{\mu}\lambda^{\lambda})^{\frac{4}{1+\lambda+\mu}}}
$$

now we need to demonstrate that

$$
\min f_{\lambda,\mu} \ge 0
$$

Note that

$$
f(\lambda,\lambda) \le f(\lambda,\mu)
$$

It is easy to verify also that along $\lambda = \mu$

$$
f(1,1) = 0\\
f'(1,1) = 0\\
f''(1,1) > 0
$$

Comment: And why is this a simplification of the original problem?

Comment: Did you try to solve it?

Comment: this just a reformulation of the problem.

Comment: A reformulation that makes it easier to solve...